# Лямбда-функция: количество всех nan значений

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Делаю агрегацию по groupby. Как бы я мог получить количество всех значений nan через lambda-функцию:

```
df_pre_result.groupby(['cohort_x', 'week']).agg({'condition':'count', 'teacher_id':lambda x: вот здесь})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При исходной df:

```
    A    B
0   1  1.0
1   1  NaN
2   1  1.0
3   1  1.0
4   2  NaN
5   2  1.0
6   2  NaN
7   1  NaN
8   3  1.0
9   3  1.0
10  3  1.0
11  1  NaN
12  1  1.0
13  2  1.0
```

делаем такую группировку:

```
res = df.groupby("A").agg({"B":lambda x: x.isnull().sum()})
```

получаем res:

```
   B
A   
1  3
2  2
3  0
```